# Installing AndEngine in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, andengine

I'm wanting to install AndEngine... I've came across Some videos that show you how to install it. But these videos were done last year, and since then, the method of installing it has changed. At lest the way they were doing it in these videos... Dose any one know the new extensions or some new tutorials I can follow...

Comment: Here is an easy to follow post that not only [sets up AndEngine but its Box2D extension](http://www.appsrox.com/android/tutorials/flappychick/) as well. Moreover, Flappy Bird is a bonus .. ;-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Keep in mind that currently there are 2 versions of AndEngine
GLES1 and GLES2, most videos and tutorials are for GLES1 as that GLES2 was recently released
also AndEngine was on google Code and now moved to github , so an old tutorial would not work
I wrote a tutorial about setting up GLES2 and getting it to work , check it out

https://jimmaru.wordpress.com/2012/04/23/setting-up-andengine-gles2-0/

Comment: Thanks... There's a video that just came out today I think... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RwMBU45IYuo&lcor=1&lc=klbJthnMGqmUmqH5I27C0otDD0zjGLoGDyx222tUY78&lch=email_reply&feature=em-comment_reply_received

Comment: if you found the answer maybe you'd like to chose one as a correct answer ?

Comment: I found my answer on YouTube... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RwMBU45IYuo&lcor=1&lc=klbJthnMGqmUmqH5I27C0otDD0zjGLoGDyx222tUY78&lch=email_reply&feature=em-comment_reply_received

Comment: It's pretty cool.. :)

Answer (score 7):

The current best practice is to set up andengine as a library project. Nicholas Gramlich, the authro of andengine, posts instructions on how to download the latest build of andengine and add it to eclipse a s a library project here:

http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles2/use-andengine-as-a-android-library-project-not-as-a-jar-t6142.html

You do *not* want to get a jar file and use that. Because there is no .jar for andengine anymore. If you are using a jar file, you are using an old version. Even if you are using GLES1, you should update to the latest code via a library project, and NOT a jar file.

Answer (score 2):

I see this is still not well explained. So i did it myself. This is my way:

1. Create your game project in Eclipse (do it as usual)
2. Download and unpack andengine from github to **and_location** (not a jar file)
3. In eclipse import whole **and_location** folder as an "Existing Android Code.." to do so right click on white space in project view and choose "Import" from context menu.
   As a root directory choose **and_location** when u do this it should (by default) mark checkbox next to "AndEngine" project. Click Finish.
4. Now you will see two projects in your workspace:

   - YourGame
   - AndEngine
5. Right click on YourGame project and choose "Build path -> Configure build path.."
6. Choose "Projects" tab
7. Click "Add" button on the right. Choose AndEngine, Click OK -> OK and Voila, you are done and you can use AndEngine classes in your project

Answer (score -2):

basically you just want to add jar file in ur project .so first download jar file from http://www.2shared.com/file/9K77Yazm/andengine.html and now you can include this jar file in your
project like this rightclick on ur project->properties->javabuildpath->add external jar->give the location of download and jar and add it.

Comment: using the jar files is no longer recommended.

Comment: hey buddy without including jar file you can't access the API of andEngine and even i already used this andEngine in my project so plz stop posting unrelevant comment

Comment: @ash. You're not right. Instead of using a jar, you download the andengine source and set it up as a library project. No jar required. To quote Nicholas Gramlich (Andengine Creator) "This means there is no 'andengine.jar' anymore"

Comment: @sturgeon the way u told to use andEngine is also right i think so u don't know about jar file concept first go through with jar file concept and then you understand my answer..

Comment: You Shouldn't use a jar file anymore.. just because it worked with you doesn't mean that it's the correct way to do it