# Using an AndEngine project in another project in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

As I understand it, when using an AndEngine project from another project, one should add it as a library, but I cannot get this to work. For example, I want to use the Andengine-PhysicsEditor-Extension. I have an Andengine-PhysicsEditor-Extension project in Eclipse, then in the other project, I go to:

- Project Properties, Java Build Path, Libaries, Add Library...
- Android Classpath Container
- Next>
- Select Project Andengine-PhysicsEditor-Extension
- Finish

So now the project compiles correctly, for example this line compiles:

```
final PhysicsEditorLoader loader = new PhysicsEditorLoader();
```

However, I get a run time error on that line:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.andlabs.andengine.extension.physicsloader.PhysicsEditorLoader

What else do I need to get this to work?

One thing that I don't understand is that the directory in the AndEngine-PhysicsEditor-Extension project:
\AndEngine-PhysicsEditor-Extension\bin\classes\org\andlabs\andengine\extension\physicsloader
is empty. Perhaps it should have class files?

Comment: If you take the time to properly format your code and errors, it will be much easier to read.  Also, let's rotate the board!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713315/installing-andengine-in-eclipse) post I think you will find it usefull, it has already been discussed on SO, basically you should use Andengine as a library project ->right click properties->android->add library after you have it as a library in your workspace

Comment: It can be worth noticing that IntelliJ 12 Ultimate does not recognize the PhysicsEditor Extension, by default, as a library module when you import it. This causes the same error as the OP has. The solution us to tick it off as a library module.