# Andengine Library setup

Tags: android, eclipse, andengine

Please help me add All `Andengine` Library.

I have imported AndEngineExamples But now it is asking me add other library reference.

Once i go in Project Properties it shows me Red cross mark in all linked libraries.

Please Please help to set my and engine libraries

Comment: follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713315/installing-andengine-in-eclipse

Comment: My own tutorial how to setup the examples project. Uses the latest GLES2-AnchorCenter branch, incl. fixed source codes. http://android.kul.is/2013/09/tutorial-andengine-extensions-and-examples.html

Answer (score 0):

- You have to download all libraries from GitHub.
- Then import all libraries into workspace.
- Download `andEngine` Examples from GitHub.
- Import this project also into workspace.
- To remove read mark errors in examples import all other libraries to this example project.

Answer (score 0):

The following link shows a video on how to download all the andengine libraries. It helped me get started:

[How to setup andengine (and everything else to get started: Eclipse, Android SDK, java, github, ...)](http://www.matim-dev.com/how-to-setup-andengine.html)

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [link](https://medium.com/@alebipin37/andengine-setup-android-studio-2017-520183e6eb5#.qj9vo11p4). It is shown with images with AS 2.2.3

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.